# C++ expected initializer before '/=' token

Tags: c++

I get a error

```
expected initializer befor '/=' token.
```

I have

```
const unsigned in array[]
```

in my loop, I have:

```
for (int i = 0; i< length; i++)
{
     while (array[i] > 0)
     {
         const unsigned int array[i] /= 10;
     }
}
```

How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you intend to divide each array entry by 10. I also assume that your gave your array a size (in the brackets). I also assume that `length` is correct.

Still there are multiple errors.

First the array should be defined `unsigned int` instead of `const unsigned in` (remove the const and fix the typo) otherwise it can not be modified.

Then remove the type declaration in the loop and use `array[i] /= 10;` instead of `const unsigned int array[i] /= 10;`.

Additionally I wonder why you try to use two nested loops? Simply remove the while loop entirely:

```
for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
{
   array[i] /= 10;
}
```

Comment: You missed the typo in the error message.  He should fix that too!

Answer (score 4):

`const unsigned int array[i] /= 10;`

should be:

`array[i] /= 10;`

---

If you write a type before a variable name, you perform a variable declaration. This is however not your intention here, you simple want to access it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to read a little up on both arrays and in more general C.
When you declare a variable with 'const' it declares it as an constant and therefor it cannot be changed later.

```
const unsigned int array[]
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
     while (array[i] > 0)
     {
         const unsigned int array[i] /= 10;
     }
}
```

Should be changed to

```
unsigned int array[];
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
     if (array[i] > 0)
     {
         // If array[i] is greater than zero, divide it by 10 
         array[i] /= 10;
     }
}
```

Ok that was the broad error fixing please checkout those links:

[How to initialize all members of an array to the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(programming)

Thanks.